# How to add shortcode tags in single.php

Tags: posts, shortcode, tags, single

In my theme has one shortcode tags to display tags of post and function to load content post. But in function doesn't include shortcode tag. Now I want to add it to function but i don't know how to do it. Hope everyone help me out. Thank in advance.

**Shortcode tag**

```
function wwl_post_tags( $atts ) {
    if( $tags = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' ) ) {

        $defaults = array(
            'before' => __( 'Từ khóa: ', 'icy' ),
            'after'  => '. ',
        );
        $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );

        return sprintf( '%1$s<span class="entry-tags">%2$s</span>%3$s',
            $atts['before'],
            $tags,
            $atts['after']
        );
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'post_tags', 'wwl_post_tags' );
```

**Function to load content post**

```
function wwl_post_content() {
    global $more;

    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        $more = 0;  
    }

    do_action( 'wwl_before_post_content' ); // Hook

    if ( ! is_single() && of_get_option('post_content') == 2 || is_search() ) :
    ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php wwl_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php wwl_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content( '', false, '' ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'icy' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>         
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a shortcode? Sorry. I really don't understand this question.

Comment: @s_ha_dum no bro, i wanna add shortcode tag into single post to display tags

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the [do_shortcode() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode). This will make WordPress run the shortcode as if it was in the content editor.

So where you want your post tags to appear just put.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_tags]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> i wanna add shortcode tag into single post to display tags

Paste `[post_tags]` into your post body via the [post editor on the backend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts).

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

If you want to do it automatically you could put a filter on `the_content` (untested):

```
add_filter(
   'the_content',
   function($content) {
     if (is_single()) 
      $content .= '[post_tags]';
     }
     return $content;
   }
);
```

Comment: i tried but nothing changed, should i add in entry-content?

Comment: You need to edit the question so that it is more clear =.

Comment: If by "entry content" you mean the big post edit box, then ___yes___. "Paste [post_tags] into your post body via the post editor on the backend."